# R error on else statement

Tags: r

I am facing an error in following script :

```
i=1
    if(i==1)
    {
        print("done")
    }
    else
    {
        print('Not done')
    }
```

Error which I am getting :

```
script.R:6:1: unexpected 'else'
5: }
6: else
```

But when I make the script a function, i.e. :

```
f=function()
{
    i=1
    if(i==1)
    {
        print("done")
    }
    else
    {
        print('Not done')
    }
}
```

It runs just fine. Am I doing anything wrong in my first script or this is an expected behaviour?

The answer here to change the bracket works, but can anyone pls share why this inconsistency ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your curly brackets as follows :

```
i=1
    if(i==1)
    {
        print("done")
    }else
    {
        print('Not done')
    }
```